# Remove border outline that appears after I click an element on my page

Tags: html, google-chrome

Every time I click an item in my page a black line appears showing the items boundaries.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to not have this line shown at all?

**Edit after Solution**
What I called a border trail is actually an outline used for easier accessibility (for example when using Tab to move around) and should actually be kept, or an alternative used in its place. For more read  MarkPlewis's comment below and the link on his answer, as well as Dirk-Jan comment on hos own answer.

Comment: I would check your css for `*:active` and `*:focus` selectors and look out for the `outline` property, this is usually not a solid but a dotted line tho.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I guess you are talking about the focus outline.

To remove it from all elements on your page use this following snippet:

```
*:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Or you can ofcourse only set it on the elments you don't want to have this outline.

Comment: It was indeed the outline attribute. All answers are correct, but since this was the first one I suppose it should be marked as the accepted one.

Comment: Do note that for some people that control sites through their keyboard it's usefull if you leave it intact (else they can't see which element they focused with e.g. tab), or ofcourse set a different styling on focus like a nice drop shadow or something.

Comment: Not only is it useful, but if you're working on a government website (depending on the country), than it's a legal requirement. The U.S. legislation is called "Section 508". Canada follows WCAG 2.0 directly. See the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines for more info: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#navigation-mechanisms-focus-visible

Comment: Very useful links, and suggestions. I should make accessibility on my site a priority. But again having that outline was not the best of options. I will have to think of some other way to let a user know what object he is currently on. Maybe a drop shadow as Dirk-Jan suggested.

Answer (score 7):

This is an accessibility feature. It allows users to interact with your website using a keyboard interface. The outline allows you to see which element currently has focus. You can suppress it with the following CSS, but it's not recommended.

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

You can [read more about it here](http://www.outlinenone.com/).

If you're working on a government website, then you may be required to follow strict web content accessibility guidelines. WCAG 2.0 level AA [explicitly states](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#navigation-mechanisms-focus-visible): "Any keyboard operable user interface has a mode of operation where the keyboard focus indicator is visible."

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can solve this with CSS:

```
*:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

This removes it from all focused elements. `*` is a selector for all elements. `:focus` is a pseudo selector for when an element is focused. And the outline you are seeing is the `outline` CSS property.